# How to delete a VLA

Tags: c++

I declared a variable length array through `new`.

```
int N;
cin >> N;
int** seq = new int*[N];
for(int i=0;i<N;++i){
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    int* s = new int[k];
    for(int j=0;j<k;++j){
        cin >> s[j];
    }
    seq[i] = s;
}
```

What's the proper way to delete the array?

```
    delete[] seq;
```

Is it sufficient? Or I have to delete the subarrays one by one?

```
for(int i=0;i<N;++i){
    delete[] seq[i];
}
delete[] seq;
```

Comment: That's not really a VLA, you are misusing that term here.

Comment: You must call `delete` for every call to `new`.

Comment: and stop using arrays and raw pointers if you didn't benchmark against vector/unique_ptr/shared_ptr. Arrays are C. Raw pointers are C. Vectors/smart pointers = C++

Comment: You have to delete subarrays one by one.